# Change Git Branch by project generated XML in Jenkins

Tags: xml, jenkins

I want to change my `xml` generated by the command of jenkins cli `get-job`, 
i get something like that:

```
.
.
<branches>*/dev</branches>
.
.
```

Im changing by `php` the value of this tag, but when i run the command `create-job` the branch name is set as `*/master` and in the `xml` is set as `*/dev`,

How can I change/set the branch name of my project via create-job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad `xml` structure of the generated `xml`, cause i use `php` `domdocument` to manage the `xml` and i try to change the value and the `domdocument` mess the document.

Now i make a test with a good one and it works.